# Possible ways of selecting x/y points that are on or close to a path in R

Tags: r, spatial-data

I am trying to extract data from a line of points which are part of a 2D map that consists of 5,000–6,000 points.
I used to be able to do this using the [Point Profile Tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/3d-analyst/using-the-point-profile-interactive-tool.htm) in ArcMap but am now looking for a way to do it in R instead, if at all possible.

In short, with the Point Profile Tool you select a start and an end point (or a polyline), which extracts the values of points that it crosses or closely passes (this closeness can be defined by a buffer value). The result is a line graph that displays the selected data along an x-axis that uses the start point as 0 and the end point as however long the line is. (do check the link above for pictures and better explanations).

**Any solutions that come to mind would be very helpful**. Obviously it doesn't have to have point&click functionality (although I had quick look at how Plotly does it). Just finding points that are close to a line and putting them into order would be a big step.

In my dataset each point has three values: x coordinate, y coordinate and elemental ratio.

```
df <-  tibble::tribble(
      ~x,    ~y,   ~ratio,
  14706, 2839, 0.381695,
  14675, 2880,   0.3673,
  14643, 2922, 0.397345,
  14612, 2963,  0.38444,
  14581, 3005, 0.348379,
  14549, 3046, 0.413543,
  14518, 3087, 0.422341,
  14487, 3129, 0.425183,
  14456, 3170,  0.41884,
  14424, 3211, 0.410218
  )
```

Comment: Have you looked at the functions `identify` and `locator` ?

Comment: Thanks @G5W! I hadn't thought of it given the large number of points, but I'm sure these functions can be used in some way.